# How to manage existing entries of channel with structure without select template from each entry?

Tags: channel-entries, channel, structure

I have install structure on existing web site. I have lots of entries. the problem is entries does not working after installing of structure. Because of entries has selected default template group. I need to manually select template group from each entries, but i have lots of entries so, it will take more time.

I have already select templates in channel settings of structure. if i select template group in entries its working properly.

If you have any solution, please let me know.

FYI:

ExpressionEngine: 2.7.2

Structure: 3.3.6

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 2):

You need to write custom script for this. You can find [script example](https://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/414-need-to-batch-change-entry-template-association) on Structure support forum. My small modification of this script (you need to create template with rights to run php code)

**!make DB backup before run the script!**

```
<?php
/**
* Batch reset template_id for Structure entries
*/

$site_pages = ee()->db->query( "SELECT site_pages
                                       FROM exp_sites
                                       WHERE site_id = 1" )->row()->site_pages;

$str = base64_decode($site_pages);
$arr = unserialize ($str);
$new_template_id = PASTE-NEW-TEPLATE-ID-HERE; //e.g. 24;

// Set new template_id
foreach( $arr[1]['templates'] as $key => $template_id )
{
    $arr[1]['templates'][$key] = $new_template_id;
}

// Serialize & encode
$new_arr = serialize($arr);
$new_str = base64_encode($new_arr);


$query =  ee()->db->query( "UPDATE exp_sites
                                   SET site_pages = $new_str
                                   WHERE site_id = 1
                                 " );   
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think yet there is no way but you can do it using sql query directly from db